# GMAP3 populating multiple marker addresses thru ajax get

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-gmap3

I'm trying to dynamically add markers to google maps using the [gmap3 plugin](http://gmap3.net/). In my code below when i pass the **variable _addressList** into .gmap(), it only shows 1 marker. to be exact, only the last marker shows **{address: "100e 800n, 84321", data: "marker 4"}**

```
// address sample format
{address: "727e 800n, 84321", data: "marker 1"}, 
{address: "900e 800n, 84321", data: "marker 2"},
{address: "200e 800n, 84321", data: "marker 3"},
{address: "100e 800n, 84321", data: "marker 4"},
```

This is my ajax get code. any idea's what i'm doing wrong?

```
        $.ajax({type: "GET",
            url: url,
            data: poststr,
            success: function(data)
            {
                var _add = new Array();
                var _data;
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                {
                  _data = '{address: "'+data[i][1]+'", data: "'+data[i][0]+'"}';

                 _add.push(_data);
                }
                            //convert string to JSON
                            var _addressList = eval("(" + _add + ")");

                $("#map-canvas").gmap3({
                    marker:{
                            values: [ 
                                _addressList
                                ]
                            }   
                });


            },
            dataType: "JSON" 
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please provide us a link of your page. Anyway I noticed your json string is not properly formatted. You can validate it at http://jsonlint.com.

The keys should be enclosed in double quotes

```
 [
    {
        "address": "727e 800n, 84321",
        "data": "marker 1"
    },
    {
        "address": "900e 800n, 84321",
        "data": "marker 2"
    }
]
```

Comment: changed  values: [ _addressList ], to values: _addressList, and added the [] into JSON, and it worked. Thanks.